# Displaying Multiple Columns Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to display papers members have uploaded to my website, the user clicks on a topic and it shows the papers which are under that topic. However my query just shows me all the papers not the ones with the specific topic.

```
//time to get our info
//time to get our info
$sql = "SELECT paper.title, paper.username, paper.abstract, paper.filelocation FROM `paper`, `topic` WHERE topic_name = 'artificial intelligence' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($file = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<h1>'.$file['title'].'</h1><br />';
    //now the file info and link
    echo '<h3>Uploaded By: '.$file['username'].'</h3><br />';
    echo '<a href="'.$file['filelocation'].'">'.$file['title'].'</a>';
    echo '<h1> Abstract : ' .$file['abstract'].'</h1><br />';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
</ul
```

Here are my tables
asso

paper_id
topic_id

topic

topic_id
topic__name

paper

paper_id
title
username
abstract
filelocation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join the two tables together with a key condition that links them:

```
SELECT
    paper.title,
    paper.username,
    paper.abstract,
    paper.filelocation
FROM `paper`
INNER JOIN `topic` on `paper`.`topic_id` = `topic`.`topic_id`
WHERE topic_name = 'artificial intelligence'
```

Otherwise you are cross joining both tables, which gives you every possible combination between the two tables.

Comment: Technically, the OP is, but hasn't specified a join condition so it's running as a cartesian join. But otherwise spot on. +1.

Comment: I used the code but i got this error message

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\ai.php on line 30

Comment: Obviously, you need to modify the column names to match your table structure.  What does your updated code look like, can you add an update to your question?  Also, the error message sounds like the query is not able to execute.  Can you dump the error, i.e., `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`?

Comment: I think it may be because i keep the topic_id in another file called associated. Although i cant work out how to use it to display the papers

Comment: Can you post your table structures, i.e., using `describe topic` and `descript paper`?

Comment: Sorry what exactly do you mean describe topic and paper?

Comment: These are queries you can execute on your MySQL database (using the command-line MySQL environment or a tool such as PHPMyAdmin) to get the table structure including all methods and relationships.  If you post this in your question, then it will be unambiguous how your tables work.

Comment: What did you mean by `I think it may be because i keep the topic_id in another file called associated.`  You store these in another physical file? or another table/column in the database?  Somehow, there needs to be a way to link the papers to the topics they belong to, otherwise you can't query for papers in a specific topic from the database.

Comment: sorry i meant in another table

Comment: I have the tables, paper, topic and asso, paper holds the details of the paper thats been uploaded, topic holds the topic name and its id. and then asso holds the paper id and the topic id of the paper as it can have ,ore than one.

Comment: Right.  in that case you need something like `paper inner join associated on paper.paper_id = associated.paper_id inner join topic on topic.topic_id = associated.topic_id where topic_name = ...`